# How to save last input Strings in Java?

Tags: java, authentication, persistence, joptionpane

The following code is a pop-up window (JOptionPane) for login and password.
How can I make my Java program to remember these two Strings: `log` and `pass` so that when the user turns off the program and next time turns it on ... the `log` and `pass` inserted last time  would be there already as default?

```
 import javax.swing.*;


    public class TestJP {

        public static String log;
        public static String pass;

        public static void main(String[] args) {



                  JTextField login = new JTextField(5);
                  JPasswordField password = new JPasswordField(5);

                  JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
                  myPanel.add(new JLabel("login:"));
                  myPanel.add(login);
                  myPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(15)); 
                  myPanel.add(new JLabel("password:"));
                  myPanel.add(password);

                  int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, myPanel, 
                           "Please Login", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
                  if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
                     log = login.getText();
                     pass = password.getText();
                     System.out.println("login: " + log);
                     System.out.println("password: " + pass);
                  }

               }

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number choices available to you, which you choose will come down to what it is you want to achiieve.

A word of warning.  I wouldn't save the password if I was you, none of the methods are hack proof.

You could:

- Use the [`Properties` API](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaPreferences/) and save and load the contents to/from a file
- Use the [`Preferences` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html) which takes care of the persistenace for you
- Some kind of database system.  You could use something like [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) or [hsql](http://hsqldb.org/) (for example) as single user databases
- You could simple write the contents to a flat file.

Each has it pros and cons.  You will need to weigh each and decide which best meets your immediate needs.

Personally, I like the `Preferences` API, but it does mean that you lose control over where the data is stored.

Comment: @nachokk That's a lot of work for little gain, especially when you consider you could just use `Properties#save` instead and save all that messing about with `ObjectStream`s and casting and the like :P - IMHO.  That might fall under *"flat file"* though I guess.  It would also be one of the reasons I might not consider using a DB for this.  There's a lot of over head involved for little benefit (in the context of the question)

Answer (score 1):

Save them to a file and read when you start up.  Examples at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html.